# how to check item is exists and renew value only in python gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

How to check item is exists and renew value only, if not exists and add new one?

For example:

I have an item 1 and value 1 already in my sheet, and then I get new value of item 1, I want to renew value 1 only, otherwise, if I get new item 2 and value 2, I want to add this in new columns.

I don't know how to write code, I search it long time but cannot found, could anyone help me? Many thanks!

The script below, the steps are:

first step, check my gmail get keyword 1

second, use keyword search datas in website (beautifulsoup module)

the last step, upload datas to google sheet (gspread module)

```
def Check_emailbox(box='Inbox', lab='SUBJECT', title='[PASS]'):    

    global email_content, report_info1, my_msg, report_info

    dirpath = 'XXX'

    with open(dirpath) as act:
        content = act.read()

    my_act = yaml.load(content, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    user, password = my_act['user'], my_act['password']

    imapUrl = 'imap.gmail.com'
    my_mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imapUrl)
    my_mail.login(user, password)
    print('Login gmail account seccess.')

    my_mail.select(box)
    key = lab                                       
    value = title                                   
    _, data = my_mail.search(None, key, value)
    mail_id_list = data[0].split()
    msg_id = mail_id_list[-1]    
    res, data = my_mail.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
    report_info = []
    if res == 'OK':
        raw_msg_txt = data[0][1]
        try:
            my_msg = email.message_from_bytes(raw_msg_txt)
            print('Subject: ', my_msg['subject'])
            print('From: ', my_msg['from'])
            print('Time: ', my_msg['date'])
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print('Content:')
            for part in my_msg.walk():
                email_content = part.get_payload()
                report_info.append(email_content)
                report_info1 = ''.join('%s' % id for id in report_info)
                print(report_info1, type(report_info1))
                # print('Hide info, if want to see detail, unmark previous code')
            print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            # my_mail.store(msg_id, '-FLAGS', '\SEEN')

        except AttributeError:
            my_msg = email.message_from_string(raw_msg_txt)
            print('AttributeError: ', my_msg)


    return email_content, my_msg, report_info, report_info1

Check_emailbox()

keyName = re.findall(r'Daily Report :  (.*?)$', report_info1)
fwName = ''.join(keyName)
print(fwName) 
# ↑ This data will be upload to sheet, and this is main item for check:
#    if "feName" is exists, renew below datas only, if not exists, add new one in next row.
    

fwVersion = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d-(.*?)-', fwName)).rsplit('.',1)[0]
print(fwVersion)   

# connect to the website and use beautifulsoup
ele = requests.get('XXXXXX')
felement = BeautifulSoup(ele.text, 'html.parser')
# print(felement.prettify())

fwinfo = felement.find(['a'], text = fwName)
fwhref = fwinfo.get('href')
print('Info: ', fwinfo)
print(fwhref)

rowid = ''.join(re.findall(r'data/(.*?)$', fwhref))
print('Download id is: ', rowid)

fwlink = 'XXXXXXXXX' + rowid
print('Download link: ', fwlink)

json_key = "XXXXXXX"
spread_url = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
connect_auth = SAC.from_json_keyfile_name(json_key, spread_url)
google_sheets = gspread.authorize(connect_auth)
sheet = google_sheets.open_by_key('XXXXXXXXX').worksheet('Pass Data')
Sheets = sheet

upload = []
upload.append(fwName)
upload.append(fwVersion)
upload.append(rowid)
upload.append(fwlink)

Sheets.append_row(upload)

print('==== Uplod to Google Sheet Done. ====')
```

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `I have an item 1 and value 1 already in my sheet, and then I get new value of item 1, I want to renew value 1 only, otherwise, if I get new item 2 and value 2, I want to add this in new columns.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue of your script and your goal? And, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault.
I use python gspread to maintain and update google sheets.
The problem I'm facing is that I want the script automatically check if the data exists. If it exists, only update the data on the value cell, otherwise, add the data column to the next row.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I think that your goal can be achieved using gspread for python. But. in order to propose a sample script, it is required to know more information. Because I cannot understand the detail of your expected situation. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this again. So, an you provide a sample input and output situations you expect as the images? By this, I would like to prepare a sample script.

Comment: Many thanks, I put my script and image in my content.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, please use your `google_sheets`.

```py
# Please set your values here.
fwName = "###"
fwVersion = "###"
rowid = "###"
fwlink = "###"

sheet = google_sheets.open_by_key('XXXXXXXXX').worksheet("Pass Data")
values = sheet.get_all_values()[2:]
obj = {}
for i, r in enumerate(values):
    obj[r[0]] = i + 3
if obj.get(fwName):
    sheet.update("B" + str(obj.get(fwName)), [[fwVersion, rowid, fwlink]], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- When this script is run, first, the values are retrieve from the sheet. And, by searching the value of column "A", new value is put to the searched row.

#### Note:

- I prepared this modified script using your sample image. In your sample image, the 1st 2 rows are header rows. And, the search column is the column "A". I used them. So, when you change your Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)
- [get_all_values(**kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=get_all_values#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get_all_values)

Comment: Many thanks!! This method very useful. I try the code and got two problems: `value_input_option="USER_ENTERED"` return error: `TypeError: update got unexpected keyword arguments: ['value_input_options']`, so I delete it, and cannot auto add new item, I need to manually input item first make item exists before run script.  But your code quite closely, now I got a way to modify. Thank you! :))

Comment: @WCJ Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script no error occurs. So, I cannot replicate `value_input_option="USER_ENTERED" return error: TypeError: update got unexpected keyword arguments: ['value_input_options'],`. I apologize for this. In my situation, the version of gspread is  5.4.0.

Comment: Don't worry, you help me resolve this problem!! Thank you anyway. :))